# What is LCTE in user-agent?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, user-agent

What does LCTE abbreviation mean in the user-agent string?

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; **LCTE**; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this source from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx) and if you compare it to user agent strings like this from [windows devices of NOKIA](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Trident%20NOKIA%29&include=yes&class=all&do=desc) the position and capitalization is indicating a device manufacturer. But a Google search for a manufacturer of Windows devices named LCTE returned nothing useful.

According to this search, your type of user agent is also [rare](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=LCTE&include=yes&class=all&do=desc) and often connected to touch devices like tablet PCs. After reviewing the agents and as I found this [discussion](https://github.com/ded/bowser/issues/89) about wrongly as mobile identified Windows touch devices like laptops and as I also found that LCTE is used in diverse [hardware component names](https://www.alibaba.com/products/F0/lcte.html) connected to displays or memory, I would conclude the following:

The string LCTE in user agents of Microsoft browsers is a result of problems retrieving the correct manufacturer from the hardware and instead, the browser is taking parts of the name of the display chipset instead. Going trough the results of this [wildcard search](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64%3B%20Trident%2F7.0%3B%20*%3B%20rv%3A11.0%29%20like%20Gecko%22&include=yes&class=all&do=desc) `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; *; rv:11.0) like Gecko"` the results are supporting this theory.

Answer (score 1):

Tools>Manage Addons>Show all Addons

or

search your registry for "LCTE",

Software vendors can insert 'tokens' into the userAgent string via registry entries. see [Understanding UserAgent Strings - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That is not true with the agents delivered within HTTP headers! From the document you provided: Earlier versions of Internet Explorer included feature tokens defined using the Pre-Platform and Post-Platform keys part of the user-agent string during the HTTP negotiation process. [...] As of Internet Explorer 9, the user-agent string no longer includes feature tokens during HTTP negotiation.